# scatter confirmation for sign a transaction?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, etherscan, meta-transactions

I have built an dapp. It's almost like twitter where the user can tweet and also use as a microblogging site in blockchain.I have used scatter as transaction signer for using my dapp.
The real problem arises when I write something in my twitter a press post button it will ask the scatter permission to sign the transaction. My question is whether is it possible to avoid the scatter confirmation to make it user-friendly.
my dapp : www.tweetblocks.com

Comment: What is "scatter"?

Comment: scatter is an alternate to metamask